# Does a wash sale make sense in downward trending stock?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, wash-sale

I buy 100 shares of ABC @ $50. I sell it in a week for $45. I buy it back in a week at $30. My understanding is that the adjusted basis for the last purchase was $35. Is that correct? If so, it seems the wash sale made sense, given the stock was trending lower significantly. Any help here appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The wash sale means that you can't deduct the realized $5 loss until your sell the replacement shares. So as noted, you adjust the cost basis of the replacement shares and indirectly claim the loss when they are sold.

Creating a wash sale makes sense if you think that owning the stock at $30 is a good idea.